# Mutating an array with apollo

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-mutation

I have a server side schema with this mutation type

```
type Mutation {
  updateSettings(settings: SettingsInput): Settings
}
input SettingsInput {
  repositories: [RepositoryInput]
}
input RepositoryInput {
  id: String
  name: String
  url: String
}
```

I can mutate this exactly like I want to if I use a client such as Altair, with this query:

```
mutation{
  updateSettings(settings: {
    repositories: [
      {
         name: "name1"
         url: "url1"
      },
      {
         name: "name2"
         url: "url2"
      }
    ]
  }){
    repositories {
      id
      name
      url
    }
  }
}
```

However I am struggling to get it working when using Apollo

The best I can get is this

```
import { SubscriptionClient } from "subscriptions-transport-ws";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
import { WebSocketLink } from "apollo-link-ws";

const wsClient = new SubscriptionClient("ws://localhost:5001/graphql", {
  reconnect: true
});
const client = new WebSocketLink(wsClient);
const UPDATE_SETTINGS = gql`
  mutation UpdateSettings($settings: SettingsInput) {
    updateSettings(settings: $settings) {
      repositories {
        id
        name
        url
      }
    }
  }
`;
client
      .request({
        query: UPDATE_SETTINGS,
        variables: { repository: [{name: "name1", url:"url1"},
                                  {name: "name2", url:"url2"}]}
      })
```

I am obviously missing something. The client doesn't seem to be aware of the servers `SettingsInput`, but I can't really figure out how to create a query for the client that takes complex objects or arrays as variables.

Am I going about this in a totaly weird way or how do I go about sending "complex" mutations to the server from an apollo client?

Comment: `subscriptions-transport-ws` is used for subscriptions. It's not an appropriate transport for queries and mutations. It's not really clear why you're using that instead of `apollo-client` or `apollo-boost`.

Comment: Mainly because I thought of it as a cleaner way to send data only through one client. I am on the side of this also using subscriptions and queries over that same client

Comment: While it may be technically possible to implement queries and mutations over WebSockets, pretty much all server-side libraries that expose a GraphQL service as an endpoint (for example, Apollo Server) only support receiving queries and mutations via POST/GET requests. Using WebSockets as a transport for these operations would require considerable work on both the front-end and backend.

Comment: You should [migrate from apollo-boost to apollo-client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.5/advanced/boost-migration) and then implement subscription support as shown [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.5/advanced/subscriptions/#client-setup).

Comment: alright, fair and valid point. however, it looks like apollo-client follows the same client query structure, so I would probably be equally confused as to how to define a list of objects as a variable to the query. But am I wrong and is this in any way handled differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client aside, you also need to fix the `variables` object you're passing in. The variable you've defined in your operation is named `settings`, but you are only passing in a variable named `repository`. Additionally, the shape of this variable doesn't match `SettingsInput` as shown in your schema. `variables` should look something like:

```
const variables = {
  settings: {
    repositories: [
      {
        name: 'name1',
        url: 'url1'
      },
      {
        name: 'name2',
        url: 'url2'
      },
    ],
  },
}
```